# Why do regression models differ when aggregated data is taken into consideration?

Tags: regression, aggregation

I have a data frame which has non-aggregated data and the another dataframe which has the same information as the first one but in an aggregated manner. When I run the regression analysis for both of these models, I expected them to be same. But to my surprise they differed. Can you please explain why this is happening.

Comment: I am surprised that you are surprised!

Comment: Without knowing how they differed it is almost impossible for anyone to clarify what is going on here.

Answer (score 2):

If aggregation means that you are combining data originating from several groups together, you might be experiencing what is sometimes called Simpson's Paradox: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox